# Restricting base template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I have a code as following, here I want to throw errors if the client code does not match any of specializations. But static assert is not helping the cause. Please suggest how to achieve it.

```
struct storage_manager{
    storage_impl<double> double_store;
    storage_impl<std::string> string_store;
    template<typename T> 
    bool try_getting(int key, T &value)
    {
        static_assert(false , "Compiler should not reach here");
        return false;
    }
    storage_manager(){}
    ~storage_manager(){}
    storage_manager(storage_manager const &) = delete;
};
```

Specialization for double type.

```
template<>
inline bool storage_manager::try_getting<double>(int key, double &value)
{
    return double_store.try_getting(key,value);
}
```

specializations for `std::string` type.

```
template<>
inline bool storage_manager::try_getting<std::string>(int key, std::string &value)
{
    return string_store.try_getting(key,value);
}
```

How to throw errors at compile time when an unsupported type is requested. like...

```
storage_manager  mgr;
int a;
std::cout<<mgr.try_getting(134,a);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
template<typename T> 
bool try_getting(int key, T &value) = delete;
```

and implement only the desired specializations. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename> void f() = delete;
template <> void f<int>(){std::cout << "ok\n";}

int main() 
{
    f<int>();
    // f<double>(); // does not compile
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ad52f6ec41c3142)</kbd>